# Invalid URL: unknown protocol: c when uploading a image to imageview javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to upload an image to an image view on java fx, I am getting the following error(runtime) when I selected an image.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: unknown
> protocol: c   at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1121)
> at javafx.scene.image.Image.(Image.java:620)  at
> me.siyum.schola.controller.AddStudentFromController.uploadStImageOnAction(AddStudentFromController.java:28)
> ... 41 more Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown
> protocol: c

Code I am trying :

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.io.File;

public class AddStudentFromController {
    public Circle circleImage;
    public ImageView imgSt;

    public void uploadStImageOnAction(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
        JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        jFileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        FileNameExtensionFilter fileNameExtensionFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                ".IMAGE","jpg", "gif", "png");
        jFileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(fileNameExtensionFilter);
        int result = jFileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

        if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            File selectedFile = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            String absolutePath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
            Image img = new Image(absolutePath);
            imgSt.setImage(img);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `Image img = new Image(selectedFile.toURL());` It seems to expect a URL

Comment: `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c` - URLs for (local) file operations start with `file://`

Comment: @g00se It expects a String representation of a URL (see [docs](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String))). Also note [`File.toURL()` is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#toURL()). Use `selectedFile.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()`.

Comment: @James_D  That's really lame. Thanks

Comment: @g00se I agree. If it wants a URL, I don't know why it didn't make the parameter type `URL`, as in other parts of the API.

Comment: Unrelated, but JavaFX has a file chooser, you should use that instead of Swing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Image` constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)) expects a string representation of a URL. To get a URL for a `File`, use `selectedFile.toURI().toURL()`. To convert to a string representation in a robust way, call `toExternalForm()` on the `URL`. So you need

```
Image img = new Image(selectedFile.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

(You can almost certainly rely on `selectedFile.toURI().toString()`; the code above just feels marginally more robust.)